# Android simulating HID Keyboard

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, adk

I want to have my Desktop machine server as a keyboard for the Android device.

In accordance with "[Android Open Accessory](http://source.android.com/accessories/aoa2.html)" protocol this should be possible:

```
AOA 2.0 allows the accessory to register one or more USB Human Interface Devices (HID)
with an Android device. This approach reverses the direction of communication for 
typical USB HID devices like USB mice and keyboards. Normally, the HID device is a 
peripheral connected to a USB host like a personal computer. But in the case of the 
AOA protocol, the USB host acts as one or more input devices to a USB peripheral.
```

I would rather avoid implementing the AOA stack, Is there any existing project demonstrating the above mentioned use-case **over windows OS** ?

How do I "reverses the direction of communication" so I could register the virtual HID devices?

Comment: Do you really need to have a fake HID device or do you just need something that acts as a remote keyboard? There are a lot of projects that achieve this in various ways: [open source example](http://www.onyxbits.de/remotekeyboard)

Comment: This is designated for implementing automated tests ( simulating user touch & keyboard events )

Comment: This seems to be the direction: http://source.android.com/accessories/aoa.html Still ACCESSORY_REGISTER_HID keeps on failing...

Answer (score 1):

I have figure it out, this ends up with switching the device to Accessory mode and sending the HID Reports to be used, then you simply send HID messages with the registered report Ids to the device.

Works like a charm

Comment: The AOA HID class is designed in such a way that it can be activated without actually switching to AOA 2.0 mode.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, do U say that AOA2 can be used w/o swicthing to accessory mode ?

Comment: HID Class can be used without enabling Audio Class and Vendor Class